# Footer buttons on dynamic dialog

Tags: primeng

I'm using a dynamic dialog and I want to have some buttons on footer, however it seems that only text is allowed for footer in this component.

```
                const ref = this.dialogService.open(TermsComponent, {
                    data: {
                        entity: response.IDEntity,
                        user: response.IDUser

                    },
                    header: this.translate.instant('resTerminosCond'),
                    width: '70%',
                    footer: `
                        <button mz-button class="btnLoginAgree" (click)="termsAccepted()" translate>
                            resAceptar
                        </button>
                        <button mz-button class="btnLoginDisagree" (click)="onAcceptTerms(false);" translate>
                            resRechazar
                        </button>`
                });
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Idk why you have to do it. Why not place the footer in TermsComponent?

Comment: There's no way to achieve that. You're better off using showHeader: false, removing all the paddings and using the p-dialog-content as you main content where you can define whatever you need to.

Answer (score 4):

use like this for latest version PrimeNG p- instead of ui- it will work.

```
<div class="p-dialog-footer">
```

Comment: It will put footer within component, instead of put it aside.

Answer (score 3):

Currently primeng does not have a feature that allows that.

But you can do this:
First set a styleClass for the dynamic Dialog.

```
this.ref = this.dialogService.open(TermsComponent, {
  data: {
    entity: response.IDEntity,
    user: response.IDUser

  },
  header: this.translate.instant('resTerminosCond'),
  width: '70%',
  styleClass: 'dynamicDialog',
});
```

Then in your app.component.scss remove the padding:

```
::ng-deep .dynamicDialog .p-dialog-content{
    padding: 0
}
```

Then in your TermsComponent.html add 2 classes. One for the content and another one for the footer.

```
 <div class="container">
      <!-- your content-->
 </div>

 
  <div class="footer">
    <button mz-button class="btnLoginAgree" (click)="termsAccepted()" translate>
      resAceptar
    </button>
    <button mz-button class="btnLoginDisagree" (click)="onAcceptTerms(false);" translate>
      resRechazar
    </button>
  </div>
```

And finally TermsComponent.scss:

```
:host {
  .container {
    padding: 3rem 1.5rem 2rem 1.5rem;
  }

  .footer {
    border-top: 0;
    background: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: right;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }

  .footer button {
    margin: 0 .5rem 0 0;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Since there's no way to use the predefined templates, we have to use the p-dialog-content as our blank canvas and put there whatever we need, even the footer or header.

Answer (score 3):

In order to add buttons in the *DynamicDialog* footer you can do the following using renderer2:

1. Define new custom type

   export type PrimeBtnObj = {text:string,icon:string,btnClass:string,callBack:(event:any) => void}
2. In Dialog component Define array of new type **PrimeBtnObj**

   ```
   btns: PrimeBtnObj[] = [
   {
     btnClass: 'p-button-text',
     icon: 'pi pi-check',
     text: 'OK',
     callBack: () => this.close() //function you want to call on click this button
   },
    {
     btnClass: 'p-button-rounded',
     icon: 'pi pi-times',
     text: 'Hello',
     callBack: () => this.ss() //function you want to call on click this button
    }
   ]
   ```
3. Wrap your content ***html of the dialog component*** inside ***div*** element with ***id*** *e.g:'content'*
4. Declare the following function in dialog component

   ```
   addBtnToDialogFooter(btns: PrimeBtnObj[]) {

   //get parent element of content
   const content = document.getElementById('content').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
   const divFooter = this._renderer2.createElement('div')
   this._renderer2.setAttribute(divFooter, 'class', 'p-dialog-footer')

   for (let index = 0; index < btns.length; index++) {
     const element = btns[index];
     const button = this._renderer2.createElement('button')
     const spanIcon = this._renderer2.createElement('span')
     const spanText = this._renderer2.createElement('span')
     const textToSpan = this._renderer2.createText(element.text)
     this._renderer2.appendChild(spanText, textToSpan)
     this._renderer2.setAttribute(spanText, 'class', 'p-button-label')
     this._renderer2.setAttribute(spanIcon, 'class', `p-button-icon p-button-icon-left ${element.icon}`)
     this._renderer2.setAttribute(button, 'class', `p-ripple p-button ${element.btnClass}`)
     this._renderer2.setAttribute(button, 'type', 'button')
     this._renderer2.appendChild(button, spanIcon)
     this._renderer2.appendChild(button, spanText)
     this._renderer2.appendChild(divFooter, button)
     content.appendChild(divFooter)
     this._renderer2.listen(button, 'click', element.callBack)
   }
   ```

   }
5. call *addBtnToDialogFooter(this.btns)* inside *ngOnInit()*

Answer (score 0):

So, this may be a late WORKAROUND, and not the best solution,but to make the Dynamic Dialog footer look alike the Dialog footer I created a custom dialog service:

```
import { Injectable, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogService, DynamicDialogRef } from 'primeng/dynamicdialog';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomDialogService{
  dialogRef!: DynamicDialogRef;

  constructor(private _dialogService: DialogService) { }
  /**
   * @param content any date you need to pass
   * @param component component to open as dialog
   * @param header dialog title
   * @param customFooter if true have a custom footer else not
   * @returns dialog reference
   */
  openDialog(
    content: any,
    component: Type<any>,
    header: string,
    customFooter?: boolean
  ): DynamicDialogRef {
    let data = undefined;
    if (content) data = { content: content };
    this.dialogRef = this._dialogService.open(component, {
      header: header,
      width: '70%',
      contentStyle: { overflow: 'auto' },
      baseZIndex: 10000,
      maximizable: true,
      data: data,
      footer: customFooter ? '---' : undefined,
    });
    return this.dialogRef;
  }
}
```

The customFooter flag defines if there will be a custom footer over the default one. This help the scroll overflow not get behind the custom footer.
Don`t forget to place it in your "app.module" in the providers.

To open the dialog:

```
...
  constructor(private _cDialogService: CustomDialogService) { }
  clickButton() {
    this._cDialogService.openDialog({}, YourComponent, 'Title', true);
  }
...
```

We will also need a css class to add to the footer div, and guarantee the scroll overflow wont be behind the custom footer.
I added this code in the style.scss, you can do it in the component that will be opened.

```
.app-dialog-footer {
  display: block !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  padding: 8px !important;
}
```

If placing it in the style.scss you will need to add "!important" at the end.

Now in the component html:

```
<div class="p-dialog-footer app-dialog-footer">
  <!-- your html content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

For DynamicDialog, you can just use primeNg class "ui-dialog-footer" and place the buttons inside it.

```
<div class="ui-dialog-footer">
  <button mz-button class="btnLoginAgree" (click)="termsAccepted()" translate>
    resAceptar
  </button>
  <button mz-button class="btnLoginDisagree" (click)="onAcceptTerms(false);" translate>
    resRechazar
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution does not work. The version I am using is `"primeng": "11.2.0"`

Comment: Did you place my suggested solution inside your html? The html should be part of the component that you are trying to open using the dialogService and not within the footer property.

Comment: It will put footer within the html of the component. Instead it shoud be aside...